# Convert webelement to string Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Hi I am currently trying to run selenium testing for a website, however I am unable to convert the webelement to string. The ErrorMessage 1 = validation which appears, therefore I want ErrorMessage1 = ErrorMessage so I know the test is successful.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\lees2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://psage.public.cs.qub.ac.uk/ForgotPassword.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_Email")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$BtnSend")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("validation-summary-errors"));
    WebElement ErrorMessage1 = driver.findElement(By.className("validation-summary-errors"));
    String ErrorMessage = "\r\n" + "                    Unrecognised email address\r\n" + "                ";
    driver.close();
    if (((String) ErrorMessage1).equalsIgnoreCase(ErrorMessage)) {
        System.out.println("Test successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test failure");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can't compare an `WebElement` with string value.You have to get text value of this webelement which is string and then compare with your expected string value.

```
if (ErrorMessage1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(ErrorMessage)) {
            System.out.println("Test successful");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Test failure");
        }
```

driver.close(); should put at the end.Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

try `ErrorMessage1.getText()` to compare the values.

**Updated:**

`WebElement` cannot be used to compare string values. It exposes `getText()` method which can be used to compare string values.

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that the website is displaying on entering an invalid email id is displayed as a `text` in the html structure. So you can simply use `getText()` method to fetch the error message from the element.

For your element, you can get the text like:

```
WebElement ErrorMessage1 = driver.findElement(By.className("validation-summary-errors"));   
String invalidEmailErrorMessage = ErrorMessage1.getText();
```

And then you can directly match this `invalidEmailErrorMessage` string with the message you want to validate with like:

```
if (invalidEmailErrorMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(ErrorMessage))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not wise to convert WebElement to String, as it is not going to yield a meaningful result.

Also you cannot compare WebElement with the string value.

To get a string value, you need to use getText() after your implementation.

***getText( ) is a Selenium WebDrivers predefined method which is used for retrieving the specified elements Text.***

**Return type** - String.

***************** **Modified Code** *****************************

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\lees2\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://psage.public.cs.qub.ac.uk/ForgotPassword.aspx");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("MainContent_Email")).sendKeys("test@test.com");
    driver.findElement(By.name("ctl00$MainContent$BtnSend")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("validation-summary-errors"));
    String ErrorMessage1 = driver.findElement(By.className("validation-summary-errors")).getText();
    String ErrorMessage = "\r\n" + "                    Unrecognised email address\r\n" + "                ";
    driver.close();
    if (((String) ErrorMessage1).equalsIgnoreCase(ErrorMessage)) {
        System.out.println("Test successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test failure");
    }

}
```

**Also instead of using this:**

```
 if (((String) ErrorMessage1).equalsIgnoreCase(ErrorMessage)) {
        System.out.println("Test successful");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Test failure");
    }
```

**Use assert:**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
Assert.assertEquals(ErrorMessage1, ErrorMessage);
```